# How to put NULL value in user input for index slicing?

Tags: python, tkinter, indexing, slice

I'm developing a program that will convert text file into json format by the keys and index input by the user. It worked when every entry boxes is filled by integer, but whenever there is an empty column, it will return error
`file_data [key3EntryName.get()]=content[int(key3EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key3EntryEndIndex.get())] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

Since I need to take `start index` to the end of the string i need to `file_data [name] = content[5:]`. But the problem is i cannot leave the `end index` empty in the entry boxes. So how can I assign a NULL value to the column that are empty ?

**My program**
[image]

**My code**

```
        try:

            for content in data2:
                file_data [key1EntryName.get()] = content[int(key1EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key1EntryEndIndex.get())]
                file_data [key2EntryName.get()] = content[int(key2EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key2EntryEndIndex.get())]
                file_data [key3EntryName.get()] = content[int(key3EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key3EntryEndIndex.get())]
                file_data [key4EntryName.get()] = content[int(key4EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key4EntryEndIndex.get())]
                file_data [key5EntryName.get()] = content[int(key5EntryStartIndex.get()):int(key5EntryEndIndex.get())]

                # output to JSON
                global tmp
                tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t") + "\n" + "\n"

                reviewjson.insert(END, tmp)

        except:
            raise
```

Comment: You can make a check first that if startindex is empty, set it to 0 and if endindex is empty, do `content[start:]`. But you have bigger issues by blindly converting the input to int. Whatever if someone provides a number that produces and IndexError? How should your script behave if instead of someone writing valid integers, they write strings instead?

Comment: If i straight away set 0 to an empty column, the script will thought the 0 is an index, and so it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function with try-except block and return None if there is an exception.

```py
def convertToInt(value):

    try:
        value = int(value)

    except ValueError:
        value = None

    return value
```

Here is an example code

```
from tkinter import *
import random

file_data = {'data1': 0, 'data2': 0, 'data3':0, 'data4': 0}

content = [random.randint(30, 5000) for x in range(50)]
print(content)

def convertToInt(value):

    try:   
        value = int(value)

    except ValueError:
        value = None

    return value
    
def update():

    for key, entry in zip(keyEntries, entries):
        
        if key.get() in file_data:
            index1, index2 = convertToInt(entry[0].get()), convertToInt(entry[1].get())

            if (index1 and index2) is not None  and index1 > index2:
                index2=None

            file_data[key.get()]=content[index1:index2]   
  
    print(file_data)
    

root = Tk()

entries  = []
keyEntries = []

for x in range(4):

    keyName = Entry(root)
    keyName.grid(row=x, column=0)
    
    entry1 = Entry(root)
    entry1.grid(row=x, column=1)

    entry2 = Entry(root)
    entry2.grid(row=x, column=2)

    entries.append([entry1, entry2])
    keyEntries.append(keyName)

Button(root, text='Update', command=update).grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

(note: keys are {'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'} and keys must be specified in the first column to update values)

Comment: Other than this method, i tried `if else` to validate every user input. It worked. But its ton of code tho